# Accessing resource file for translation not working for all controls using asp.net Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, c, multithreading, webforms

Accessing resource file for translation  not working for all controls.
It only works for controls that allows the resource class to access using
"<%= Resource.Identification %>" and not for others that uses
"<%$ Resources:Resource,Identification %>".

Using asp.net Web Form.
On the login Interface, when a User selects a language, i change 
the below C# code snippet below to change the application language.
The cultureKey variable could be "en" or "fr".

**"System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureKey);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureKey);"**